# Call stack error when creating binary tree with recursion

Tags: c, stack, runtime, call

The following code runs for a second and then a runtime error is caused by node->data = *data;

```
 Node *TreeCreate(int level, const char *data)
{
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (node != NULL) {
    node->data = *data;
    }

    if (level != 0) {
        node->leftChild = TreeCreate(level - 1, data + 1);
        node->rightChild = TreeCreate(level - 1, data + (int)pow(2, level - 1));
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: `data + 1` and `data + (int)pow(2, level - 1)` you sure you are doing it right?

Comment: that is used to find the appropriate char in my string, its dependent on the order that i put the chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you reserved at least pow(2, level) characters for the string referenced by *data the next TreeCreate() call just fall off these boundaries:

```
TreeCreate(level, data) //--> 
    TreeCreate(level, data + 1) //--> ...
    TreeCreate(level, data + pow(2, level-1) // -->
           TreeCreate(level, data + pow(2, level-1) + 1) //-->  well still may fit to you string
           TreeCreate(level, data + pow(2, level-1) + pow(2, level-2) // --> may not fit
```

For example, level = 4, size of the string pointed by data = 16, when walking down the TreeCreate() call tree for leftChild will result in:
data + 4 + pow(2, 3) + pow(2, 2) + pow(2, 1) --> data + 18 (!!)

Comment: You are correct, my goal was to create a tree
               A children:
         B          C,
B with children:
      D   E   and C with:   F   G

given the string "ABDECFG." going top-down left-right.
Running TreeCreate(3, the string) results in a call stack error which I now believe is a result of my code going passed the number of chars it has.

Comment: The error was caused by my malloc, I it needed to be sizeof (Node) instead of sizeof (node). As for the data, a four level binary tree will have 15 characters and my if statement should be (levels > 1) rather than (levels != 0) so that it does not go passed that 15th char. All is working now, thanks for your help.